# call function a fixed time after starting vim

Tags: vim

I would like to call a function that performs some actions a fixed time after it is called, (say 30 seconds). The function could be called right in the initialization or sometime during the usage.
While I wait I would just keep using vim as usual. Would this be possible?

If it helps I am using vim compiled with perl and python and I and have the addon vimproc.

Comment: What do you need that for? Why must it be delayed? How flexible are you about the amount of delay?

Comment: OK, the reason I would like this is the following: I load some plugins on demand because the machine where I run things is sometimes very slow. I use the function commmand `:ActivateAddons <addon>` to load a specific plugin. But it would be nice if I could do this in the background say 5 - 10 seconds after starting.  The time would be flexible but I don't want to use autocommands.

Comment: Just start Vim 30 seconds earlier :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your best candidate are the `CursorHold,CursorHoldI` events. They fire when the user has paused for 4 seconds, so it happens frequently, but it's also likely he won't notice the slow operation that is triggered then.

You cannot avoid that Vim blocks; especially not for loading slow plugins. Vim(script) is single-threaded; no background processing is possible. While you can use (carefully!) the multi-threading support of integrated (Perl, Python, ...) interpreters (for background tasks), this is no help when you need to "call back" into Vim core, which you need to do for plugins written in Vimscript.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following:

```
if has('python') "{{{ LoadPythonDelayed
function! LoadPythonDelayed()

python << ENDP
import time
from threading import Thread
import vim

def LoadAddonPy():
    time.sleep(2)
    vim.command('call LoadAddon()')

Thread(target=LoadAddonPy).start()

ENDP
return ''
endfunction

call LoadPythonDelayed()
endif
```

it seems to work so far, maybe there it might trigger bugs (I will put here if it does).
One thing I note so far is that by using this I cannot quit vim before the thread exists.